# Symmetric difference of finite and infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If the difference of two sets : A - B is finite, then at least A or B must also be finite
If A equals all even integers {2,4,6...}, B equals integers that are divisible by three {3,6,9,12..}

Then A-B = all even integers that are not a multiple of 3. However the difference in this case would infinite. Is this true for all cases.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry let me emphasise the question i am asking is: If A − B is finite, then at least one of A or B must also be finite.

Comment: Have a look at special case $A=B$. Here $A-B=A-A=\varnothing$ hence is finite, but $A=B$ might be infinite anyway.

Comment: There is no use in Posting some Question & then unnecessarily "Deleting" it later when it has been Correctly Answered.

Answer (score 1):

Consider A = {c} U B and c is not belongs to B, where B is infinite. Then A and B is infinite, but A - B = {c}.